# Can Dimension Door be cast into Leomund's Tiny Hut?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, teleportation

In tonight's session, the party came across a Leomund's Tiny Hut. The party's bard chose to cast Dimension Door into it. This caused a bit of a (friendly) disagreement among the party, and none of us had an answer that solidly convinced the other side.

[Leomund's Tiny Hut](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/tiny-hut) states:

> Creatures and objects⁠ within the dome when you cast this spell can move through it freely. All other creatures and objects⁠ are barred from passing through it. Spells and other magical effects can't extend through the dome or be cast through it.

[Dimension Door](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dimension-door) states:

> You telepo⁠rt yourself from your current location to any other spot within range. You arrive at exactly the spot desired. It can be a place you can see, one you can visualize, or one you can describe by stating distance and direction, such as “200 feet straight downward” or “upward to the northwest at a 45-degree angle, 300 feet.”

The disagreement stemmed from the use of the word *through*. Dimension Door doesn't launch anything or move the person *through* anything; you *teleport*, technically never crossing the barrier of Leomund's Tiny Hut. Instead, you completely bypass the Hut's walls and simply appear inside of it, and as a result it would not be blocked by Leomund's Tiny Hut's effects.

On the other hand, my interpretation is that Dimension Door is still *extending through* the Hut. You would need to be able to magically connect yourself from where you are to where you want to be, and that magical connection would be blocked by the Hut's barrier, causing the spell to fail.

None of us were able to find a solid answer, and after some google searching we could find nobody bringing up this circumstance.

**Is it possible to cast Dimension Door through a Leomund's Tiny Hut, using the loophole that you *technically* never pass *through* the barrier?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## You *Cannot* Teleport Into the Tiny Hut

A key, though subtle point to this opinion is a statement on *Range* in the PHB (203)

> Once a spell is cast, its effects aren’t limited by its range, unless the spell’s description says otherwise.

The suggestion is that ***during and before spell casting*** the spell's effects ***are*** limited by range.

Jeremy Crawford weighs in on this issue [here](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2017/12/24/cast-dimension-door-inside-prismatic-wall-can-i-teleport-outside-all-layers-of-wall-because-isnt-forbidden/), specifically in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/933437785075097600):

> The indigo layer of prismatic wall prevents you from casting spells through it. This doesn't stop a spell with a range of self, such as misty step, but it does stop dimension door, which has a range of 500 ft.

and Leomund's Tiny Hut (PHB 254):

> Spells and other magical effects can’t extend through the dome ***or be cast through it***.

Because of it's range of 500 ft, casting Dimension Door to teleport into the Tiny Hut would involve casting the spell **through the dome** and cannot be done.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer even though the other response has significantly more upvotes. Crawford's tweet makes it very clear that spells with language preventing "casting spells through" a barrier will also block Dimension Door, making the upvoted answer incorrect.

Comment: OK, but you may use Gate, right?

Comment: So you can Misty Step but not Dimension Door?

Comment: This answer should be clarified to indicate that "Teleport" in the title means "use the Dimension Door spell to teleport", rather than "use the Teleport spell" or "use any form of teleportation".

Comment: @EttinaKitten keep in mind misty step is blocked if you cannot see into the hut.

Comment: If you can't cast Dimension Door through the barrier of prismatic spray or tiny hut, by Crawford's reasoning, it seems that you can't cast dimension door through, for example, a window (which also blocks all spells, by virtue of being total cover.)  I don't think that's intended or how anyone plays; but we can maybe ignore Crawford's reasoning, and just accept that the intention is DD doesn't go through these kind of magical barriers, but Misty Step does.  (Dream is another example where RAW and intention regarding total cover don't jive.)

Answer (score 20):

## You *can* teleport into the Tiny Hut.

Spells that restrict or block teleportation make specific reference to teleportation. In particular this one:

- (PHB 252) *Imprisonment (Burial)*:

  > ...Nothing can pass through the sphere, nor can any creature teleport or use planar travel to get into or out of it.....

The description of the Burial aspect of the Imprisonment spell clearly illustrates that "passing through" and "teleportation" are two different forms of travel and are thus each clearly restricted for this spell.  For more examples see:

- (243) *Forbiddance*
- (213) *Antimagic Field*
- (243) *Forcecage*

Which all specifically restrict teleportation to different degrees. Leomund's Tiny Hut has no such restrictions, it only restricts "passing through it."

They can teleport into the hut.  However...

#### Teleporting into the Tiny Hut using Dimension Door is not without risk.

The Tiny Hut's dome is opaque, and then there's this aspect of Dimension Door (PHB 232):

> If you would arrive in a place already occupied by an object or a creature, you and any creature traveling with you each take 4d6 force damage, and the spell fails to teleport you.

So while you **can** teleport into the Tiny Hut you can't see where you're going, and it would be easy for the DM to hamper the effort and make it both futile and dangerous (4d6).

---

**Please Note:** The comments on this answer may be in response to the answer ***You Cannot Teleport Into the Tiny Hut***, which is also my response. That answer was initially in the same post as this answer, but was later moved to its own post.  ***You Can*** was my first answer, and I had a change of opinion when some new facts presented themselves.  My current opinion is that ***You Can't*** and you can see why in my other answer.  I've left this ***You Can*** opinion intact as a record and to add to community discourse.

Comment: "Spells that restrict or block teleportation make specific reference to teleportation." Note, that the Hut's description talks about a spell extending through the dome, while the Imprisonment talks about something passing through it. I sense a semantic difference here.

Comment: Can you state by which basis do you use that clarifying comments in one context imply their opposite elsewhere within D&D 5e rules?  Is there a developer comment stating this?

Comment: You might add that once inside, a creature would have to teleport to get back out as well -- the dome is still impassable to creatures that weren't initially inside.

Comment: I've checked the referenced spells and while you are correct that teleportation is handled specifically, this answer does not address the fact that Leomund's Tiny Hut states that spell effects cannot extend through it or that spells cannot be cast through it. This is the entire sticking point of the question.

Comment: @Baron You're right.  My answer was wrong.  I'm rewriting it with new information.  Thanks.

Comment: "Casting Dimension Door to teleport into the Tiny Hut is considered casting through the dome" — why do you say so?

Comment: 1. Because Jeremy Crawford says so. But 2, more importantly, why he says this: the *Range* of the spell indicates the area/distance in which the spell is cast. So the magic extends through that range, either the area or in a straight line. I wouldn't have ruled this way until today when I dug up the JC ruling. Still wrapping my head around it and wondering where else this might be impactful. I'll edit the answer to clarify when I get home to a keyboard.

Comment: force cage only blocks casting spells in one of its two forms so it has to say it blocks teleportation to do so, forbiddance only exists to block teleportation, imprisonment does not block spells so to block teleportation it again has to state it. all the other spells have specific reason they would need to specifically call out teleportation.

Answer (score 0):

## You *can not* teleport into the Tiny Hut.

While spells that restrict or block teleportation make specific reference to teleportation. Leomund's Tiny Hut restricts "Spells and Magical Effects". Is "Dimension Door" a spell or magical effect? Yes, Dimension Door is a spell. Is it being cast from outside the hut? Yes

Therefore they can **not** teleport into the hut. Specifically because the spell goes **through** it. Define through: "From one side to the other, from one end to another, in and out the other side" The dimension door goes from one side of the dome to the other side, it therefore goes through it as well as any creature passing through the dimension door would be going through it.